# How to measure the rate of popping/pushing per second in a queue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, queue, c++-chrono

If we assume we have a typical implementation of a queue (with a linked-list representing the nodes, a counter, a push method and a pop method) what would be the best way to measure the rate of a arrival and rate of departure of new items to the list? Would I require two separate threads, one two measure each rate?

Any pseudo code/ideas would be most welcome!

(I just quickly wrote this to help with any answers. Omitted templates for simplicity)

```
class my_queue{
public:
    struct Node{
        Node* next;
        Node* previous;
        int data;
    }

    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int queue_size;

    my_queue(){}

    int pop(){
        Node* old_head = head;
        Node* new_head = old_head->previous;
        new_head->next = null;
        head = new_head;
        int data = old_head->data
        delete old_head;
        queue_size--;
        return data;
    }

    void push(int data){
        Node* new_tail = new Node();
        new_node->data = data;
        Node* old_tail = tail;
        old_tail->previous = new_tail;
        new_node->next = old_tail;
        tail = new_tail;
        queue_size++;
    }

    int getSize(){
        return queue_size;
    }
};
```

Comment: Instead of modifying your code you can use a profiler that gives you function call counts. Run the program with the workload you want to measure for a give period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty simple: You just use two atomic push/pop counters that are incremented for each operation. You then use one thread that runs every second, records the current state (or does whatever it wants with it) and resets the counters back to 0.

The only thing you have to take care of is to use a timer that accounts for the time spent in your function to make sure you don't drift too far away from the 1 second intervals (also you should copy the two counters and reset them at the start if you spend nontrivial amounts of time processing).

Comment: @MartinJames I'm only having a single consumer-producer anyway.